# Awk: string negation with ANSI escape seqences

Tags: bash, awk

I have a function setup to tail a file in color.

```
function testtail {
tail -f -n100 $1 | awk '/SNMP/ {print "\033[1;33m" $0 "\033[39m"}' 
}
```

This works as expected and prints all lines that contain SNMP in my specified color but how would I tell awk to also negate any line with string SNMP so that lines that do NOT match SNMP prints in another color? I have tried:

```
function testtail {
tail -f -n100 $1 | awk '/SNMP/ {print "\033[1;33m" $0 "\033[39m"}' '!/SNMP/ {print "\033[1;34m" $0 "\033[39m"}'

}
```

And this:

```
function testtail {
tail -f -n100 $1 | awk '/SNMP/ {print "\033[1;33m" $0 "\033[39m"}' | awk '!/SNMP/ {print "\033[1;34m" $0 "\033[39m"}'

}
```

But neither work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like you are looking for an if-else condition:

```
... | awk '{if ($0 ~ /SNMP/) {print "\033[1;33m" $0 "\033[39m"} else {print XXX}}'
```

Where `XXX` can be whatever you want.

Or more idiomatically:

```
... | awk '/SNMP/ {print "\033[1;33m" $0 "\033[39m"; next} {print XXX}'
```

---

Since these are the strings you are printing:

- `"\033[1;33m" $0 "\033[39m"`
- `"\033[1;34m" $0 "\033[39m"`

You can in fact use a variable to set 33 or 34 and keep the rest untouched.

Comment: @Paul thanks for your edit! Note however that `print` and `print $0` are entirely equivalent. If I wrote `XXX` was not to write all those `\033` etc :D

Comment: Both of these solutions work, however when I ctrl c to kill the testtail command my prompt turns red. Any Idea what thats all about?

Comment: @user53029 this is because you left some opening code there.

Comment: apparently it did not like the "[39m" so went back to just "[m" and all is well. Answer is yours.

Comment: Yes. the $0 in the else part is not necessary. I just blatted the XXXs without changing the answer. Added a bit more C to the MCVE.

Comment: @PaulHicks I see. However, `print "$0"` would print a literal `$0`.